Какие знаки возможны + какой лучше?
Ясное дело, что двоеточие верно: Кто сильнее: ферзь или две ладьи?
А запятая и тире подходят?
Кто сильнее (,) ферзь или две ладьи?
Кто сильнее (—) ферзь или две ладьи?

Изменения хороши, но я не уверен насчет скобки с запятой, написанной слитно. Розенталь ее раздельно писал («Факультативные знаки препинания»). Спасибо за ответ на вопрос!

Максим, да, я знаю, как в справочнике, но, думаю, это уже не Розенталь писал, в электронных версиях вообще можно найти много недочётов. А здесь мы привыкли скобки с запятой не отделять от слова, ведь сама запятая не отделяется. Так "логичнее" выглядит, к тому об этом вроде нигде не сказано...

@АлександрСтрелец Ладно, как скажете, не буду спорить с вами

Запятая в таких предложениях не лучший знак, хотя в непринуждённой, бытовой переписке и она сойдёт. По правилам, по интонации и в силу взаимодействия частей подходят и двоеточие, и тире.
Я чаще выбираю тире:
Кто сильнее — ферзь или две ладьи?
См. ответ на аналогичный вопрос.

Скажите, пожалуйста, какова грамматика этого предложения? Можно дать ответ по общим правилам правописания, а не в соответствии с готовыми решениями?

@Sharon  Грамматика, наверное, такая: кто – подлежащее, сильнее – сказуемое, остальное – уточнения: Кто – ферзь или две ладьи – сильнее? // Не понял про готовые решения...

Почему (по какому правилу) уточнение можно обособить тремя разными знаками, в том числе двоеточием?  К тому же здесь инверсия.

@Sharon По правилу Розенталя о параллельном использовании знаков (см. ссылку на такой же вопрос, вы не раз видели это правило).

Это и есть готовое решение Розенталя. Можно объяснить выбор знаков правилами по теме "Уточняющие члены предложения"?  Или это какая-то другая тема из общих правил?  Я об этом.

@Sharon Что плохого в готовом решении? Уточнения, пояснения, приложения и даже вставки  можно оформлять по-разному, факторов много. // Что вы относите к общим правилам, а что нет? Какая другая тема? Тема описана Розенталем, и я правда не понимаю, о чём вы :))

А можно ссылку на пункт из правил  (уточнения, пояснения, приложения, вставки  и т. д.).  Именно для такой структуры предложения. Я правда не могу понять, откуда три знака для одной грамматики?:)) У Розенталя ведь не спросишь, как он решил  эту задачу...  Не люблю пользоваться правилом, которое не понимаю.  Представьте, что правила о параллельном использовании знаков нет.  Можно как-то самим решить задачу или нет?  Нашему участнику Максиму  нужны три знака и какой лучше.

@Sharon Именно для такой структуры Розенталь и написал пункт 6 в параграфе Двоеточие – тире. // Я написал, что запятая хуже. Двоеточие или тире выбираем исходя из задачи, специфики текста, интонации.

Ладно, спасибо, извините, что отвлекаю.

@Sharon Сами и решаем, опираясь на практику письма и закономерности, замеченные и выявленные Розенталем.

Нет, не сами. Мы все у Розенталя списываем. Привяжите три знака к заданной структуре предложения,  У Розенталя частное решение.

@Sharon Я написал: "решаем, опираясь". // А Максиму пора бы уже приводить контекст.

Я не понимаю смысл его вопроса. Тире и двоеточие для такой структуры рассмотрел Розенталь, он это, верно, знает. А запятая откуда?

Предлагаю решить задачу о выборе знаков следующим образом.

Кто сильнее(?) ферзь или две ладьи?

Это БСП, бессоюзная связь. В правой части назывная конструкция "ферзь или две ладьи".
В общем случае возможны три знака. Выбор тире или двоеточия зависит от ударения, что определяется по контексту.
(1) КтО сильнее — ферзь или две ладьи?
(2) Кто сильнЕе: ферзь или две ладьи?
(3) Кто сильнее, ферзь или две ладьи? Разговорный вариант, нет подчеркнутой паузы.

Сравнить: Какой знак лучше(?) запятая, тире или двоеточие?

Решение: Какой знак лУчше: запятая, тире или двоеточие?
Здесь только двоеточие (ударение в конце первой части).

Запятая самый редкий знак, при бормотании: "И не то чтоб мы не понимали, что хорошо, что худо; спросите у первого встречного: что лучше, в чистоте ли жить или в грязи барахтаться — наверное, всякий скажет: как можно! в грязи или в чистоте!" С.-Шедрин.

То есть, когда вообще про выбор речи не идет, а есть некое повествование, не связанное с постановкой вопроса. "Не знаю, для чего это он говорил и что лучше, если афиша такому знатоку нравится или не нравится — это большой вопрос." Телятников.

Фраза с запятой: "...что лучше, в чистоте ли жить или в грязи барахтаться". Эта структура подчиненная, она только часть основного предложения,  Поэтому ставится запятая: мы не можем здесь поставить сильный знак, в том числе по произношению.

Ну можете быть. (я, если честно, не разбираюсь, я чисто визуально, что вижу, то и рассказываю=)) Просто мне всё-таки в вашем ответе не хватает литературных примеров в качестве аргументации.

Литературные аргументы я беру у вас, а у меня общая СХЕМА решения. Я объясняю возможность ТРЕХ  знаков  для предложения, построенного по образу БСП с  НОМИНАТИВНОЙ конструкцией.  Такое предложение может быть частью сложных синтаксических конструкций, как в вашем примере, где поставлена запятая. У Розенталя говорится об уточнение/пояснении, по по грамматике это именно БСП со значением уточнения/пояснение, а не ПРОСТОЕ предложение, как можно подумать.

У меня нет аргумента с запятой. Хотя это конечно же лестно)

Вопросы. Просто интересно. 1. Почему всё-таки БСП? У Розенталя это обособление пояснительных и уточняющих членов предложения: Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, десять?;  Сколько мне тогда было (: —) девятнадцать или двадцать?; Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) в среду или в четверг. // Наш пример такой же. // 2. Почему в КтО сильнее можно поставить ударение на "кто", а в Какой знак лучше нельзя на "какой"? Из-за чуть большей длины? // 3. Само предложение "Какой знак лучше: запятая, тире или двоеточие?" вызывает сомнения. Знаки не могут быть лучше друг друга


Наш пример такой же, кто спорит. Но вы ведь сами не догадаетесь, что это БСП с номинативной конструкцией и с пояснительными отношениями. Вот и пришлось Розенталю вспомнить про пояснительные члены, ведь до этого в п. 4 и 5  он использовал  БСП для объяснения. Но странные они такие : запятой нет, зато почему-то есть двоеточие. И очень уж далеко вопросительное местоимение от поясняющей конструкции. Вывод: по грамматике это БСП, а по семантике пояснительный член  в виде номинативный конструкции.



Да, больший объем первой части, делать ударным вопросительное местоимение не очень удобно. Здесь тоже номинативная конструкция, но у Розенталя такого примера нет. Как будете решать?  Вам же нужен такой же пример, как у него. 3. Предложение неполное, это всего лишь шапка вопроса, заданного на форуме. А подробное содержание дается отдельно.


Я к вам... а вы... (и так уже стараюсь не задавать вам "лишних" вопросов) Хочу понять ваши решения и то, зачем нужно было выделять отдельный пункт о поясн. и уточн. чл., если всё это описано в 5 пункте о БСП. Чем наши примеры отличаются от примеров пункта 1 об однородных членах: Что её больше волнует — уход мужа или то, что... Мы оба художники (: —) и ты и я. А этот пример почему не с ними, а в пункте 6: Потом началось главное (: —) поиски, нащупывание новых путей...// Ихь ферштэе нихьт, например, почему больший всего на одно слово-слог объём не удобен для ударного вопр. местоимения. И пр.

А вообще, спасибо вам ещё раз за ответы и за то многое, что дали и даёте мне и этому ресурсу!

Благодарю за новые вопросы. Не знаю, смогу ли ответить на них, у меня мышление блочное и довольно примитивное))  Хочется проще и быстрее. Но я подумаю,  может быть... Хотя не уверена.  Наверное, вам лучше не расставаться с Розенталем.  Зачем лишняя информация? Лучшее враг хорошего, а уж худшее тем более Это все юмор, не обращайте внимания, S...   You are my good friend now, as before.

Хотя пару слов скажу. Не надо объединять разные структуры предложений. То, что укладывается в правила для пояснительных членов, пусть решается по этим правилам в соответствии с ГРАММАТИКОЙ.  Зачем вам еще-то?  Это в первую очередь касается присоединительных конструкций с тире. Но вот двоеточие вызывает сомнение.   Да и запятая тоже, если местоимение удалено от поясняющего члена предложения.  // Больше всего на один слог?  А я могу добавить: "Какой знак в этом предложению будет более обоснованным: запятая, тире, двоеточие или точка с запятой?"  Можно поставить запятую или тире?

Запятую нет, тире да (по правилам). А ударением и в этом случае можно выделить первое слово. На то она и вариативность. Свободе научили меня вы :)  Помню, я вас просил как-то на время забыть о Розентале, о "старых" правилах, а теперь вы мне советуете не расставаться с ними :))

Я не то чтобы советую,  но опасаюсь, что вам трудно будет без Розенталя.  Не готовы вы  еще к полной свободе  и  настоящей вариативности.  Сейчас не вспомню, но мне приходилось решать задачи для БСП такого вида,  то есть с номинативной конструкцией.  И никто не возражал, и никто не предложил другого решения. Ладно, время покажет, кто свободен, а кто нет.  Почему, к примеру,  никто не решает задачи блоками?  Вы, например?  У Розенталя этого нет или метод нехорош?

Умная мысль в заключение))  Розенталь писал свои правила не для того, чтобы ему поклонялись и носили его справочник в кармане.  Он хотел, чтобы  мы были грамотными по сути, по внутреннему пониманию грамматического строя русского языка и связанных с ним правил. Чтобы учились на его образцах, а не заучивали их наизусть, как цитатник.


Главная причина, кто сильнее: преподобный Прокопий али Гарусов? Мамин-Сибиряк.


Великий спор идет между временем и вечностью в человеке о том, кто сильнее: Добро или смерть? Соловьёв.

Я выбираю двоеточие, по классике, тире тут будет кручено-перекручено, вроде такого:

Судить о том, что выше, поэзия или нравственность, так же трудно, как
выяснить — кто сильнее, слон или кит, и трудно именно потому, что это
совершенно разные вещи. Довлатов.

Или такого:

Спорить нелепо, это разговор на детском уровне: кто сильнее — кит или слон? Владимир Соловьёв( не тот, что в начале)

так что:
Кто сильнее: ферзь или две ладьи?  - без вариантов.
Из обсуждения "Какой знак лучше(*)тире или двоеточие?":
Лучше - не указывает на критерий выбора, поэтому тут возможна постановка тире, на усмотрение пишущего, однако, постановка тире встречается реже - примерно 1 к 3, чем постановка двоеточия(у тире больше несколько примеров, но далеко не все примеры связаны с выбором, а где двоеточие - почти все). Тире, я думаю, указывает на пропуск чего-то, в данном случае критерия выбора, однако, если критерий очевиден, то ставится двоеточие.

Выбирай, что лучше — глупая смерть или жизнь, полная таких радостей, которые пока только снились тебе, да и то так редко, что даже обидно. Шварц.


"Что лучше: ушлют или умрет?" Лесков.


"Я не знал только, что лучше: молча ли проскакать, или крикнуть?" Толстой.


"... а также полемику о том, что лучше: национализировать разом банки и промышленность — или можно ограничиться только банками?" Данилкин.

Так же двоеточие может предполагать более основательное рассуждение и выбор далее, а не просто выбор из а, б, с - как в случае с тире. Также имеет место быть постановка знаков ".. : .. - .. или ..":

Видя источники тяжбы и преступления тому и другому, найти иногда возможно будет преграду, и что лучше: держать всегда подъятый меч для казни преступных деяний, или самые деяния преобразить, зиждительным образом сделать их невинными, не давая им возродиться. Радищев.


— Стихами или задачею: что лучше — желать и не получить, или иметь и потерять; а то по цветам: что какой цвет означает — верность или измену. Лесков.


Но вопрос этот у нас никогда иначе и не ставился: «Что лучше — мы или народ? Достоевский.


...и заставляет его тяжко задуматься: что лучше — любовь или деньги. Успенский.

Также большая часть постановки тире в период после 1960 года. Двоеточие - это знак рассуждения и повествования, а тире - больше про восприятие и впечатление, когда хочется добавить экспрессии, и часто, когда ответ на вопрос вторичен.
Самый редкий знак - запятая. Её постановка возможно при повествовательном бормотании - то есть когда речь идет вообще не про дилемму, а про что-то связанное с вопросом, и скорее всего рассказ о событии в диалоге:

"Не знаю, для чего это он говорил и что лучше, если афиша такому знатоку нравится или не нравится — это большой вопрос." Телятников.

"И не то чтоб мы не понимали, что хорошо, что худо; спросите у первого встречного: что лучше, в чистоте ли жить или в грязи барахтаться — наверное, всякий скажет: как можно! в грязи или в чистоте!" С.-Шедрин.
Резюмируя:
Если критерий выбора ясен, то только двоеточие.
Если критерий нужно додумывать, то двоеточие, если про "подумать", порассуждать, а если про риторический вопрос, лозунг и прочая экспрессия, тогда допустима тире.
Также возможна схема вопроса в высказывании после двоеточия - ".. : .. - .. или ..?"
В редких случаях, когда идет косвенное повествование о дилемме, содержание вопроса вторично, можно ставить запятую.

Как вы оформите такое предложение: Какой знак лучше(,) запятая, тире или двоеточие?

Лучше для чего или лучше чего?

Какой знак лучше поставить: запятая, тире или двоеточие? Какой знак лучше вопросительного -  запятая, тире или двоеточие? Может так?)

Мы разрешаем вопрос о том, что лучше — гласность или молчание?С.-Щедрин, - у слова "лучше" нет критерия, "сильнее" - критерий силы. Если критерий добавить - то двоеточие, это полное предложение. А если критерий отсутствует и "догадайся сам" - то тире.

Задан вопрос н форуме: Какой знак лучше(,) запятая, тире или двоеточие?   Как его правильно записать?

Какой знак лучше - запятая, тире или двоеточие? - 40/60 ставят тире. "Что лучше: чтобы дети старалися угождением своим заслужить благоволение отца, нежели чтобы отец видел детей своих не брегущих о нем, надежны в наследии своем." Радищев. - 60/40 двоеточие.

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CsICEp4CCpsCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJnCg8KA2xleBIICgbRh9GC0L4KCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKCwoFZ3JhbW0SAgoACgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoMCgZzeW50YXgSAgoACgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKABKBAQoJCgNsZXgSAgoAChQKBGZvcm0SDAoK0LvRg9GH0YjQtQoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgwKBnN5bnRheBICCgAKEwoFZmxhZ3MSCgoIKGJjb2xvbikKDAoEZGlzdCIECAEQASoYCggIERAKGDIgChAFIABABWoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBATAB

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CsECEp0CCpoCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJnCg8KA2xleBIICgbRh9GC0L4KCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKCwoFZ3JhbW0SAgoACgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoMCgZzeW50YXgSAgoACgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKABKAAQoJCgNsZXgSAgoAChQKBGZvcm0SDAoK0LvRg9GH0YjQtQoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgwKBnN5bnRheBICCgAKEgoFZmxhZ3MSCQoHKGJkYXNoKQoMCgRkaXN0IgQIARABKhgKCAgAEAoYMiAKEAUgAEAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBMAE=

"...что лучше — и лучше тоже — ближе, нормальнее.." - такой ответ устроит?)

"Что лучше: ушлют или умрет?"  Лесков. Вообще, двоеточие обычно предполагает более детальное рассуждение, а не просто выбор из а, б, в. "Я не знал только, что лучше: молча ли проскакать, или крикнуть?" Толстой.

Спасибо!  Я думаю, выбор тире или двоеточия  зависит от конкретного предложения.

"Что лучше — не знаю: у всякого свой вкус." Островский. За нас ответил).

Но это только когда критерия выбора нет, а когда есть, только строго двоеточие.

Вот я задаю вопрос на форуме (название вопроса): Какой знак лучше(?) запятая, тире или двоеточие?  Тире написать иди двоеточие?

@Sharon я добавил в ответ обобщение вышесказанного.
